# Calculated column offset by 2

Tags: powerbi, dax

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTjZv.jpg
I am trying to generate a calculated column B from column A. Notice that column B is basically the same rows as column A except it's offset by 2 rows. I'm trying to generate this with DAX but I don't even know where to begin. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. You need to define what "offset" means. In Excel, it means "Row number". In DAX, a concept of row number does not exist. You need to provide a field that defines order (i.e, date, or "sort order", etc).

Comment: @RADO is correct, you will need something to use as a point of reference. This can be easily done in SQL, just add a row number. BTW Why do you need to do this anyway?

Comment: @Steliok I'm trying to calculate a third column for Cash Factor which takes the Charge Amount from 2 months before into account. The data comes from a DirectQuery in SQL as data source for Power BI.

Comment: You should add a date time to indicate what month each payment is associated, add the first of the month to every payment and it will be relatively easy for you to create.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in PowerBI the PowerQuery Editor to append a Column with 2 "null" values (as numeric type) like the example below:

[append column in powerbi example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP6nF.png)

To get this result:

[final result of "column B"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np0r7.png)

Think is a easy way to get what you want.